# For Sharepoint pie chart webpart, is it possible to group small slices into one "Other" slice?

Tags: chart-web-part

The Sharepoint pie chart webpart has about 10 slices. Unfortunately, you can't read the labels of the 5 smallest slices as they are all cramped together. Is it possible to group them together as one "Other" slice?